# Automatically starting a JBoss service (MBean)

Tags: java, jboss, service, jakarta-ee, mbeans

I'm trying to build a JBoss service that should be started automatically, each time the server is initiated.

I've got the following class structure for my service:

```
public interface CumbiaXPMServiceMBean extends org.jboss.system.ServiceMBean
public class CumbiaXPMService extends org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport implements CumbiaXPMServiceMBean
```

I've also got the following configuration file -- jboss-service.xml -- for my service :

```
<server>
    <mbean code="uniandes.cumbia.xpm.jboss.CumbiaXPMService"
       name="jcumbia:service=JCumbiaEngine">
      <depends>jcumbia:service=cumbiaConsole</depends>
      <attribute name="LocationInCumbia" attributeClass="java.lang.String">XPMEngine</attribute>    
    </mbean>
</server>
```

My question is: how do I automatically start this service?

I expected that JBoss will call the method start( ) as part as the loading process, but it is not: I've got a lot of loggin code in my start( )  method, but I haven't seen any output.

However, when I look at the MBean status using the JMXConsole, its state (StateString) is 'Started'.

**Problem Solved**

I found the solution to my problem. I was overriding the methods start( ), stop( ), destroy( )  and create( ); nevertheless, since I'm extending the abstract class ServiceMBeanSupport, I should be overriding the methods startService( ), stopService( ), etc.

I just moved my code from the method start( ) to the method startService( ) and now everything is behaving as I needed: as soon as its dependencies are fulfilled, my service is started and the method startService( )  is executed.

I think the conclusion is: although the life-cycle of an MBean involves calling create( ), start( ), stop( ) and destroy( ), the implementation of the abstract class ServiceMBeanSupport uses those methods to handle the life cycle. Nevertheless, it provides the protected methods *Service( )  in order to allow the programmer to participate in the life cycle.

Comment: "automatically"?  Doesn't the service "start" when the app server is started?  If the JMX console says it's started, what behavior makes you believe it has not?

Comment: I've got some logging code inside the start() method, but it is not being executed. I have some logging code in the constructor of the class, and I can see its output, but that's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

I found the solution to my problem. I was overriding the methods start( ), stop( ), destroy( ) and create( ); nevertheless, since I'm extending the abstract class ServiceMBeanSupport, I should be overriding the methods startService( ), stopService( ), etc.

I just moved my code from the method start( ) to the method startService( ) and now everything is behaving as I needed: as soon as its dependencies are fulfilled, my service is started and the method startService( ) is executed.

I think the conclusion is: although the life-cycle of an MBean involves calling create( ), start( ), stop( ) and destroy( ), the implementation of the abstract class ServiceMBeanSupport uses those methods to handle the life cycle. Nevertheless, it provides the protected methods *Service( ) in order to allow the programmer to participate in the life cycle.

Answer (score 2):

For me it helped defining the stop and start methods in the MBean Interface:

```
public interface MyServiceMBean {
    ...

    // Lifecycle callbacks
    void start() throws Exception;
    void stop();
}
```

The advantage is that you don't have to extend ServiceMBean oder ServiceMBeanSupport.